# Error installing MikTEX under Windows 10

Tags: errors

When trying to install basic-miktex-2.9.6161-x64 at W10, I get the following error:

[image]

Can anyone help me, please? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try to install as administrator?